# Delay between repeated AJAX call to a web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.Net web app with jquery implemented on the client side.  within a while loop, the client side jquery script makes an asynchronous call to a web method in the server side code.  The call returns the status of a long running server side task which jquery uses to update the user.  The goal is to have jquery repeatedly call the server until the status is complete, once done it breaks out of the while loop and notifies the user thatthe task is complete.

My problem is that the below code runs in a while loop, but I want to make it delay or sleep between each call in order to prevent overwhelming the server with status requests.  I tried calling setTimeout in the code below, but it only works with the initial ajax call, every subsequent call occurs back to back.  Is there a way to efficiently delay each subsequent call to the server?  Is this the most efficient way to achieve the kind of behavior I'm describing?  Ideally I'd like a 2-5 second delay between each call.

I have the following code

Client Jquery:

```
var alertTimerId;
$('input[name=btnStatus]').click(function () {

    var result  = false;
    //Loop while server reports task complete is true
    while (!result) {
      alertTimerId = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/GetStatus",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function (msg) {
            if(msg.d != false)
              result = msg.d;
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('AJAX failure');
          }
        });
      }, 2000);


      if (count > 0) {
        count--;
      }
    }


  });
```

Server Side ASP

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static bool GetStatus()
        {
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like the following? The idea is that the Ajax call is encapsulated in a function, `doAjax()`, and then from within the Ajax success handler if the result is false you use `setTimeout()` to queue up another call to `doAjax`, otherwise you take whatever action you want to take for a true result. (You could optionally call `doAjax()` from the Ajax error handler too.)

```
$('input[name=btnStatus]').click(function () {

    function doAjax() {
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/GetStatus",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function (msg) {
             if (!msg.d)
                 setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
             else {
                 // Success! Notify user here
             }
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('AJAX failure');
          }
       });
    }

    doAjax();

});
```

(Note: I've removed the if statement with `count`, since it seemed to have no relevance to the question. If your real code uses it just update it within the Ajax success handler too.)

Comment: I would add `setTimeout(doAjax,2000);` to the error handler function as well, so the chain of requests is not broken if one of the ajax requests timesout.

Comment: @shaun5 - I guess it's up to the OP whether that's appropriate, but I _did_ mention it in my explanation. (I probably wouldn't bother with a timeout in the error case though because there's already an alert so there'll be a slight delay while the user deals with that. Might be better to change the alert to a confirmation message about whether to retry or abort.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - This works wonderfully, didn't think to use a recursive call.  My only concern is, will the client-side buffer or whatever other caching medium jQuery uses to store its function queue (my apologies for not fully understanding how jQuery stores the queue references), be filled or even overflow, especially with very long processing tasks on the server-side?  Just curious if this would be an issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not really a recursive call. The `setTimeout()` statement queues up a call to `doAjax()` that will occur after the specified delay but in the mean time execution continues immediately with whatever statement is after `setTimeout()` so in this case the current success callback will end. There'll only ever be one Ajax call in progress at a time, and only one timeout queued at a time. Definitely not the same as saying `doAjax()` directly from within `doAjax()`. Note: `setTimeout` is not a jQuery thing, it's a plain JavaScript thing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore.Js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle) has a `.throttle()` helper function:

> **throttle_.throttle(function, wait)**
>
> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked
>   repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once
>   per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that
>   occur faster than you can keep up with.

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```