# ASP.Net connection keep alive for long running server-side task

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net C# web application, running on IIS, that I'm supporting which involves generation of word documents.  Some of these word documents take a very long time (i.e. upwards of 20-30 minutes) to generate.  What I notice while testing on my dev server is that the server closes the connection long before the process completes, the server-side ASP.Net code itself enters a loop and updates the status of a boolean value when the word doc generation completes.

My workaround for this is to keep the connection alive by implementing a dynamically animated wait screen ( using jquery and ajax) on the client-side that's updated by a repeated asynchronous AJAX call to the server that checks on the status of the operation from a server-side web method.  I'm asking about that piece in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660819/delay-between-repeated-ajax-call-to-a-web-method).

Is the solution I'm looking at implementing the best approach to this problem?  Are there more efficient or common methods for keeping the connection alive during a long running server-side operation?  Any help or insight is appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried Brian's suggestion, unfortunately I still get the same error from Chrome that no data is being sent from the server and the entirety of the error is as follows:

> No data received Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no
>   data.
>
> Here are some suggestions: Reload this webpage later.
>
> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection
>   without sending any data.

I'll try again by setting the connection timeout in the advanced website settings as described and increasing the connection idle setting.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd use a socket to notify the client when the process completes. Look at socket.io or native web-socket implementations on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Esteban, this sounds like a potential alternative to my load screen, which isn't working quite as expected yet.  Would it be possible to integrate a socket connection during a postback from my ASP.Net webform application.  Then have that pipe status information back to the client browser?  I'm just curious how the browser would handle data send from a socket connection, as opposed to receiving a direct response from the server.

Comment: SignalR does a great job of wrapping up web-sockets (and fallback alternatives). This way instead of the client polling the server (as in your already-mentioned implementation), the client maintains a connection to the server that issues a callback to the client when the task is completed.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/

Answer (score 0):

You can control Idle time within IIS 7. This is done by going to IIS management; select application pools; then right click on the pool your using for your website. Click the "Advance settings" here you will be able to control idle time out and some other settings for your website. Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm testing this solution now, initially I tried configuring the Connection Timeout value in the advanced settings of my Default Website, but that didn't seem to have an affect, Chrome, for example, throws "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.".  IE will just idle and eventually throw a "Unable to Display Webpage" error.

Comment: From the error messages you posted it looks like the website you are trying to hit is not running. I would check the app pool and the website in IIS to see if the are playing. I would restart or refresh them just in case. Also, Check your web.config to see if you have any timeouts there. Something else that helps me is to run Firefox with the firebug add-on. This will help catch any error.